# How do I get forward_name if I get an error?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram

I write on the Python Telegram bot. And I need to get the name of the user and his id, whose message was answered with the word-command.
I have a code in which two people interact, the sender's name and id are displayed normally, but the problem is that the second does not work.

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "[{0.first_name}](tg://user?id={0.id}) killed [{1.first_name}](tg://user?id={1.id}) ".format(message.from_user, message.forward_from),
    parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

And the console displays this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Comment: That exception suggests that at least one of `message.from_user` or `message.forward_from` is `None`, rather than whatever you expect it to be.

Comment: One of `message.from_user, message.forward_from` is equal to `None`. You need to figure out which one, and why...